# Is there a way to add a url(not to the file itself) to assets?

Tags: assets, url

I am testing Craft to see if it would be a good fit for sites I build.  At this point, I do feel it is great and might fit most of the work I do.  The only thing I can't figure out is how I could add a url to images to build a logo gallery (ie: list of logos that link to the partners websites).

Is there a way to do this by default?  I can't find any information on it.

Comment: Hey Eric - Are the images listed in an entry field somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any number of fields to your asset sources (just like you can for 'user groups', 'category groups', 'tag groups', or 'entry types'). Under 'settings > assets > sources', click a source (or create new); then click the 'field layout' tab and add your field (field needs to be created first); and save. For a url you would likely just use a textfield.

In your template you would access it with something like this:

```
{{ entry.myAssetsFieldHandle.first().myLinkUrlFieldHandle }}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I totally missed the fact that you can set fields on Asset types. This makes it very flexible.